# Why does this appear to be differentiable when it shouldn't?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification

This feels stupid enough, yet it escapes me. Someone help me?

Let $$f(x):=\begin{cases}x, & x<0 \\ x+1, & x\ge 0 \end{cases}.$$ Then since it is discontinuous at $x=0,$ one should not expect it to be differentiable there. To show this from the definition is what seems to be a problem for me, for we have $$\frac{f(0+\delta)-f(0)}{\delta}=\frac{(0+1+\delta)-(0+1)}{\delta}=1,$$ so that taking limits from either direction leaves it unfazed and solidly $1,$ which is nonsense since it cannot be differentiable there.

Please help!

Comment: You need to consider negative $\delta$ as well, and there we have $f(0+\delta)=\delta$.

Comment: @fleablood That's incorrect - a discontinuous function is never differentiable, so the differential quotient *has* to go "wacky".

Comment: I was talking about the limits of derivatives not the differential quotient. ($f'(x)_{x < 0}$ is equal to $f'(x)_{x > 0}$)  But your comment is relevant and mine is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{f(0-\delta)-f(0)}{-\delta}=-\frac{0-\delta-1}\delta=1+\frac1\delta.$$

The right derivative exists, not the left one.

Comment: Ah... Dang middle aged eyes!

Comment: @fleablood: mentored by Euler ?